# const float* a и float* const b

Tags: c

Понимаю: если **const** находится слева от * , то *данные* константа.
Если **const** находится справа от * , то **указатель** константа.

*Вопрос : что означает, что указатель константа?*
    Пишу следующее:

```
int main()
{
    const float* a;
    float g = 5;
    float* const b=(float*)malloc(g*sizeof(float));
    b[0] = 6.4; // на это спокойно реагирует
    float* k = b++; //инкремент не работет
    return 0;
}
```

Почему же инкремент не работает ?Что означает, что указатель константа?

Comment: Поставьте `++` слева, а не справа от `b`, инкремент должен заработать. В приведённом коде `k` сначала получает значение `b`, а потом `b` увеличивается.

Comment: Указатель константа означает, что значение по указателю можно изменить, а сам указатель нельзя. То есть, например, выполнить для константного указателя операцию `++` не получится.

Comment: @Mark Shevchenko: И с чего бы это вдруг `++` слева от `b` "должен заработать"???

Comment: @Ant, потому что `++` слева сначала делает инкремент, а потом уже возвращает результат. `++` справа возвращает результат, который был до инкремента.

Comment: @Mark Shevchenko: И что? Проблема то в том, что кто-то пытается менять неизменяемый указатель. Неизменяемый указатель невозможно поменять. Неважно, с какой стороны вы навесите на него инкремент, код компилироваться не будет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Понимаю: если const находится слева от * , то данные константа. Если
>   const находится справа от * , то указатель константа.

Некоторые C-программисты предпочитают следующий стиль объявления переменных (обратите внимание на первый квалификатор `const`: он стоит *после* `float`):

```
float const * const * var
```

В таком случае становится легко применять правило чтения «справа-налево»:

```
                      var | переменная var — это
                    * var | указатель на
              const * var | константный     
            * const * var | указатель на
      const * const * var | константный
float const * const * var | float
```

Впрочем этим правило можно пользоваться независимо от выбранного стиля.

> Вопрос: что означает, что указатель константа?

Это означает, что вы не можете изменять этот указатель! Смотрите, в чем дело.

```
char num = 10;
char * const ptr = &num;
```

Здесь у нас есть две переменных:

1. `num` — переменная типа `char`. В ячейке памяти, выделенной для этой переменной хранится число 10.
2. `ptr` — константный (неизменяемый) указатель на изменяемые данные типа `char`. `ptr` «указывает» на переменную `num`, т. е. в области памяти, выделенной для `ptr` хранится адрес переменной `num`.

`ptr` — **неизменяемый указатель**, это значит, что мы не можем сделать так, чтобы `ptr` указывал в какое-то другое место кроме `num`. Он всегда будет указывать на `num` и повлиять мы на это не можем (законными путями)!

`ptr` — неизменяемый указатель на **изменяемые данные**, это значит, что сами данные, на которые указывает `ptr` мы изменить можем (т. е. можем изменить значение переменной `num`).

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, в языке С `const` объекты не принято назвать словом "константа". Термин 
"константа" в языке С означает совсем другое. `42` - это константа, `3.14` - тоже константа, ваше `b` - не константа, а `const` указатель.

Во-вторых, в данном случае то, что указатель объявлен как `const` означает, что значение указателя нельзя модифицировать. Инкремент "не работает" потому, что инкремент пытается модифицировать указатель.